# Laptop to Desktop PCI-E passthrough Thunderbolt 3

Tags: laptop, desktop, pcie, thunderbolt

I currently have a laptop and a desktop PC, one for work, one for games, and I wish to use the same peripherals for both using TB3 somehow.

The ideal solution would be to have a Thunderbolt 3 splitter/switch but I couldn't seem to find a reasonably priced option or anything at all.

I recently purchased a BenQ PD2710QC, which has a Thunderbolt 3 dock built into it. It works beautifully with my laptop and peripherals but only has one TB3 input.

If I install a Thunderbolt 3 PCI-E card (like this [Gigabyte Alpine Ridge Dual Thunderbolt 3 Type C PCI Card](https://www.mwave.com.au/product/gigabyte-alpine-ridge-dual-thunderbolt-3-usb-typec-pci-card-ac03973)) in my desktop, plug one port in from my laptop and plug the other into the BenQ PD2710QC - could it work? Or is there a better way to approach this, besides changing cables every time?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand what you are asking you want to use the same keyboard, mouse, and screen on both

So there is this cool gadget called a KVM, this allows you to switch between your different devices, but you can't use your desktop and laptop at the same time

But there is a software solution, something I use is synergy https://symless.com/synergy
I set my laptop right next to my desktop monitor and use the same keyboard and mouse on both at the same time

Comment: Seconding Synergy, it's a great software solution for what you seem to be trying to accomplish. Do note that you don't have to pay for it; the core components are open source, and [there are built versions through 1.8.8 available for download free](https://github.com/brahma-dev/synergy-stable-builds), with some forks floating around that purge the activation requirements for some of the features.